# remove the '0' from a string after calculation

Tags: c

im trying to to multipication in two string;
after i'm done the code shows me the answer with all the '0' from the calloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef char* verylong;

verylong input_long(void) {
    int len = sizeof(char),size=0,c,i=0;
    verylong num = malloc(len);
    char ch;
    size = len;
    if (num != NULL) {
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
              ch = (char)c;
             if (isdigit(ch))
                num[i++] = ch;
             else
                 return NULL;
             if (i == size) {
                size = i + len;
                if ((num = realloc(num, size)) == NULL)
                   return NULL;
            }
        }
   }
   else
       return NULL;
   num[i] = '\0';
   return num;

}

verylong_multiply(verylong num1, verylong num2) {
int long1 = strlen(num1), long2 = strlen(num2);
verylong ret = calloc(long1 + long2 +1, sizeof(char));
_strrev(num1);
_strrev(num2);
int carry = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < long2; i++) {
    int dig2 = num2[i]-'0';
    carry = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < long1; j++) {
        int dig1 = num1[j]-'0';
        int temp = ret[i+j]-'0';
        int cur = dig1 * dig2 + temp + carry;
        ret[i+j] = cur % 10+'0';
        carry = cur / 10;
    }
    if (carry>0)
        ret[i+long1] = carry +'0';
}

_strrev(ret);
return ret;
}
void main() {
char* a = input_long();
char* b = input_long();
printf(multiply(a, b));
}
```

this is the whole code, the output seems to keep give me the answer of the two string (10*10) 580, it keeps adding the multiply if '0' (48 in ascii).

Comment: Not 'verylong' again:(   You should explain that type is a typedeffed char pointer - all the other posters did.

Comment: i did on an early function,

Comment: If I understand your code, it's saving the digits as character array, ready to be printed. Consider having the digits stored in the array as numeric values in the opposite direction ("123" -> {3, 2, 1}) alongside with the size of the number, in a struct, to ease the computations. You are probably using those in math operations more frequently than just printing them, so it would make sense to "optimize" that kind of usage.

Comment: Also, if `verylong` is a typedef of `char *` (which is a bad idea of its own), the first `return '0';` is wrong.

Comment: the code save's the number after the calculation, but because i used "calloc" to build the new string, it keeps the '0'. if i make 10*10 it gives me 580. 100+10*'0'(480)

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems other than the general design of the algorithm and the data structure (a struct which stores the size alongside with an array of digits, starting from the least significant one, would ease all the calculations).

```
verylong_multiply(verylong num1, verylong num2) {
if (strlen(num1) == 0 || strlen(num2) == 0) return '0';
```

Here there is at least a copy-paste error, either the function is `verylong multiply(...)` or the return type is missing. Also, if we assume (and we shouldn't) that `verylong` is a typedef of `char *`, that `return '0';` is plain wrong. `'0'` is a `char`, not a `char *`.

There seems to be a confusion, throughout the whole snippet, between `'0'`, `'\0'` and `NULL`.

This line

```
verylong ret = calloc(sizeof(char) , long1 + long2 + 1);
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Those should be switched
```

Will allocate the array and fill it with *zeroes*, not `'0'`.

If you want to fill it with `'0'` (except for the null-terminator), you could use

```
memset(ret, '0', long1 + long2);
```

So that, later in the code, you could also change this line

```
int temp = ret[i+j];                   //  -->    int temp = ret[i+j] - '0';
int cur = dig1 * dig2 + temp + carry;
ret[i+j] = cur % 10 + '0';
```

Thrn, before reversing the string and return it, you could transform the eventual last `'0'` into `'\0'`, to avoid having, say, `10 * 123 = 01230` instead of `1230`.

Note that the chosen data structure forces you to reverse the strings representing the numbers and to calculate their lengths *every* time you call this function and you should also reverse them back to their original state, if you plan to use them again.

Comment: after i'd changed it the output is the same, i will copy the whole code to review but thanks for answer me.

Comment: @DanielLevi If you are talking about the edited code in the question, you missed a couple of suggestions: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NQtxl2PCVXEvDwS5.

Comment: @DanielLevi As I already commented, though, consider storing the arbitrary sized number in a [struct](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ojd4MsexnlzT0J8y).

Comment: thank you alot Bob you were very helpful i appreciate it.